# Aggregate network traffic by destination IP

Tags: linux, ip, centos-7, network-traffic

The bandwidth usage of my server almost suddenly doubled from 4.5TB to 8.5TB per month. I don't see a corresponding increase in my website traffic.

Is it possible to find out top network traffic destinations and the hourly outbound data transfer to those IPs?

I tried several utilities like `iftop`. But I am able to see only the current transfer rate, and not the aggregate data over a period.

Comment: What distro? What sort of services is this for?

Comment: The distro is CentOS 7. I have installed ntopng, according to which HTTP is responsible for most of the data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO turning on logging in iptables/ipfw/pf (whatever firewall) and parse it later would give you precise picture